# CPP, How to connect to sqlite3 db from string

Tags: c++, sqlite

In my program I need to connect to sqlite db from string.

I receive the sql db (UTF-8) as string from the user, I'm using the `sqlite3_open` function that receives file path of the db file so I'm creating a file, write the string to it and using it to connect to the db:

```
sqlite3*
SQLiteUtils::ConnectToDatabase(std::string const& dbStr)
{
    sqlite3* db;

    std::ofstream dst("sql.db", std::ios::binary);
    dst << dbStr;

    int const ret = sqlite3_open("sql.db", &db);
    if (SQLITE_OK != ret) {
        LOG_ERROR("Can't open database: " + std::string(sqlite3_errmsg(db)));
        CloseConnectionToDatabase(db);
        return nullptr;
    }

    return db;
}
```

Is there a way to connect to string without writing the string to file and connect to the file?

Comment: Could you explain what you have in the dbStr? Because your database is the sql.db file and you should not write data to that by yourself.

Comment: I receive the sql DB as string from outside, I create the "sql.db" file and write the string to it so I can connect to the the received data.

Comment: I am using the ```int sqlite3_open(const char *filename /* Database filename (UTF-8) */, sqlite3 **ppDb /* OUT: SQLite db handle */)``` API that receive file as DB.     My question is if there a way to connect to string and not file?

Comment: Is using the sqlite lib to create a temporary in-memory database from the string (assuming it contains `Create table ...`etc.) an option?

Comment: Thanks @Yunnosch,  It could be, can you write an example please?

Comment: Please provide an example of the string you want to turn into an accessable database.

Comment: The string is the db from another sqlite, export the db with ```sqlite3_backup_init```, read from the ```.db``` file and sent to me as string

Comment: Look into `sqlite3_serialize()` and `sqlite3_deserialize()`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Shawn in the comments I used `sqlite3_serialize()` and `sqlite3_deserialize()`.

This solution work for me:

```
const char* IN_MEMORY_DB = ":memory:";

sqlite3* ImportDatabase(const std::string &dbStr)
{
    sqlite3 *db;
    int ret = sqlite3_open(IN_MEMORY_DB, &db);

    if (SQLITE_OK != ret)
    {
        return nullptr;
    }        

    // give serialized buffer ownership to SQLite
    unsigned int flags = SQLITE_DESERIALIZE_FREEONCLOSE|SQLITE_DESERIALIZE_RESIZEABLE;

    // allocate the serialized buffer from heap, SQLite requires to dynamic allocation for deserialize to work correctly
    unsigned char* data = static_cast<unsigned char*>(sqlite3_malloc(dbStr.size()));

    if (nullptr == data)
    {
        sqlite3_close(db);
        return nullptr;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < dbStr.size(); ++i)
    {
        data[i] = static_cast<unsigned char>(dbStr[i]);
    }

    int err = sqlite3_deserialize(db, "main", data, dbStr.size(), dbStr.size(), flags);
    if (err != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        sqlite3_close(db);
        return nullptr;
    }

    return db;
}
```

In this solution I allocate the sql memory and copy the string to it without writing the data string to file in the middle.

Answer (score -1):

> How to connect to sqlite3 db from string

The default behaviour of `sqlite3_open` is to open/create the db, and so the only thing you need to do is:

```
int const ret = sqlite3_open(dbStr.c_str(), &db);
                          // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks @Andreas, I see in the [SQLite C Interface](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html) , that the first argument of ```sqlite3_open``` is the db file path, can it get the db data as argument as well?